# How to search users inside group in Keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Using Keycloak 11.0.3.
I trying to search users inside group using Keycloak API:

```
List<UserRepresentation>  users = realmResource.users().search(username, firstname, lastname, email,
    0, 100);
```

But when I try to get groups of found users I get null even if user have group:

```
List<String> groups = users.get(0).getGroups(); //It's null
```

So how to search users inside group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the groups that a user belongs to try with the following:

```
realm.users().get(userId).groups();
```

Use the userID instead.

To get the users of a given group do the following:

```
realm.groups().group(groupId).members();
```